# KVM loss of data?

Tags: filesystems, kvm, virtualization

I'm planning to install KVM on Linux Mint. I heard it is possible to corrupt files and partitions. There are warnings [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/279571/lvm-dangers-and-caveats) but I haven't finish reading it (I will tonight). There is also another warning [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/articles/40643)

Is it possible to mount drives and partitions to a VM? Say my host is Mint and I'm running a Windows guest and Debian guest; Is it possible to accidentally have it mounted on both guest systems and cause a corruption? What if a guest system is using it could I accidentally access files/write to them on the host and corrupt files?

I have no experience and its a big deal if it corrupts my 2TB HD (just one big partition) or my 200GB partition on other drives or any external USB drives (1-2TB).

Comment: The link you gave talks about LVM, while your question is about KVM. Which one are you asking about?

Answer (score 2):

It's always possible to corrupt filesystems, it's the nature of the beast.

#### Setups

However, I've been using KVM at work & home for over 3+ years now and we've never experienced a single issue. We run a mix of guests, mainly CentOS, Ubuntu, and Windows Server 2008R2. The KVM hosts are CentOS 5 + 6.

#### Accessing Shares

We typically mount shares to them over the network, we never mount local bare metal partitions from the host into the guests. Rather we run Samba on the the host and then share folders into the guests as needed.

The only other interesting thing we do is one of the guests is running our provisioning system, Cobbler, and that system uses NFS to share out a directory containing all the ISOs for the various OSes that we need to built/support.

This allows us to spin up new VMs over the network without any installation media such as DVDs etc.

#### Robustness

We've had power outages (they're quite frequent in our area) and the KVM hosts have regularly lost power and we've never had a single issue with either the host or the guests coming back up.

#### Disk layout

We did nothing special in our setup. We setup ext4 partions and then put an LVM volume on top of them. This is stock for how Feodra/CentOS/RHEL do disk layouts.

Let me know if you have further questions, I can provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you stick to `cache=none` you shouldn't have any issues, and it is best practice not to use the other options anyway.